# Java generics reference not working

Tags: java, android, generics

Not sure what's going on here, I'm trying to do something really simple, set an object by reference. I wrote the same code twice, once setting the object by reference, once returning the new object and setting it there. Here's the code

```
for (Person p : test) {
    bcPetDao.refreshRef(p.pet);
    Log.e("Woo1", "Name:" + p.pet);
    Log.e("Woo1", "Addess: " + p.pet.hashCode());
}
for (Person p : test) {
    p.pet = bcPetDao.refresh(p.pet);
}
Log.e("Woo2", "Name:" + test.get(0).pet);
```

And the code for refresh and refreshRef is:

```
public T refresh(T object) {
    try {
        String id = cachedClass.idEntry.getKey().get(object).toString();
        return queryOne(new Query(cachedClass.idColName + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null, null, null, null));
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

public void refreshRef(T object) {
    try {
        String id = cachedClass.idEntry.getKey().get(object).toString();
        object = queryOne(new Query(cachedClass.idColName + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null, null, null, null));
        BcLog.e("In Ref name is: " + object.toString());
        BcLog.e("Addess: " + object.hashCode());
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Is there something with Java generics that makes this not just work? Here's the log printout.

```
04-23 22:50:55.643: E/BcLog(30237): In Ref name is: ID: 119, name: 3fdb2a3ab1c0a2e8
04-23 22:50:55.643: E/BcLog(30237): Addess: 1090746752
04-23 22:50:55.643: E/Woo1(30237): Name:ID: 119, name: null
04-23 22:50:55.643: E/Woo1(30237): Addess: 1087524160
04-23 22:50:55.663: E/BcLog(30237): In Ref name is: ID: 118, name: 3fccb118500e0f1c
04-23 22:50:55.663: E/BcLog(30237): Addess: 1088206960
04-23 22:50:55.663: E/Woo1(30237): Name:ID: 118, name: null
04-23 22:50:55.663: E/Woo1(30237): Addess: 1087682616
04-23 22:50:55.684: E/BcLog(30237): In Ref name is: ID: 117, name: 3fe026bb4d24bfe2
04-23 22:50:55.684: E/BcLog(30237): Addess: 1088359352
04-23 22:50:55.684: E/Woo1(30237): Name:ID: 117, name: null
04-23 22:50:55.684: E/Woo1(30237): Addess: 1090724368
04-23 22:50:55.714: E/BcLog(30237): In Ref name is: ID: 116, name: 3fe26d6a3967d838
04-23 22:50:55.714: E/BcLog(30237): Addess: 1090659992
04-23 22:50:55.714: E/Woo1(30237): Name:ID: 116, name: null
04-23 22:50:55.714: E/Woo1(30237): Addess: 1088417312
04-23 22:50:55.734: E/BcLog(30237): In Ref name is: ID: 115, name: 3fef8ec496c0cdb2
04-23 22:50:55.734: E/BcLog(30237): Addess: 1088221128
04-23 22:50:55.744: E/Woo1(30237): Name:ID: 115, name: null
04-23 22:50:55.744: E/Woo1(30237): Addess: 1088572064
04-23 22:50:55.824: E/Woo2(30237): Name:ID: 119, name: 3fdb2a3ab1c0a2e8
```

Comment: What are you looking to do?

Comment: Update p.pet to have the newest values from my DB. It does not work after the 1st foreach (by reference) but does after the 2nd for each (return the new object).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java is pass-by-value. When you invoke `refreshRef( object )`, the method will have a local copy of the object *reference* (consider it a pointer), so assigning this reference within the body of the method will not affect the object you passed in.

As there is only one copy of the object in memory, you can change members of the object you have a reference to, but you can not change the instance itself.

Comment: No, it won't. Though Java is pass-by-value, the absolute value being passed is the object pointer. There only exists one copy of the object in memory.

Comment: Yup, that definitely makes sense. Now I feel silly, thank you. I was under the impression that it was real pass by value because properties will change, but you are right, updating the reference itself will not work.

Comment: @Telthien, I didn't say it passes a copy of the object, but a copy (value) of the object reference. So if the copy (`T object`) is changed within the method, this change does not propagate to the invoking code. However, if the object members are changed, this change will propagate, as the object exists only once.

Comment: LOL, thx. I re-read it myself a couple of times before I posted. Clarified it somewhat.